# how to get the information of new handle in blackberry

Tags: blackberry

getModuleHandles() gives me array of all module handles but i want the handle of new installed application on the device..So is there is any way by which i can get the information of newly installed handle in OS 4.5

thank u.

Answer (score 0):

```
int moduleHandle = CodeModuleManager.getModuleHandle("YOUR_MODULE_NAME");
if(moduleHandle == 0){
    Dialog.alert("Module not found.");
else{
    ApplicationDescriptor ad = CodeModuleManager.getApplicationDescriptors(moduleHandle)[0];
}
```

You now have the ApplicationDescriptor object of the installed application which is exactly what you require.

Comment: but i dnt know the module name...i want to get the hamdle of any third party application installed on my device...

Comment: can you elaborate on what you want to achieve? Perhaps we can help after knowing exactly what you want to achieve.

Comment: I don't want to allow any third party application installation on my device...so for that i want to delete that third party application which is installed on my device....

Comment: If you don't want any third party (non-RIM, non-Carier) programs then don't install any, and remove application management permission from any applications you do install. Much better solution than trying to catch them being installed.

Answer (score 0):

Create a background app which will run when device is started and after that it is always running in background. Now add [CodeModuleListener](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/system/CodeModuleListener.html#modulesAdded%28int%5B%5D%29)
to your background application. Listen for any new modules added using [modulesAdded()](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/system/CodeModuleListener.html#modulesAdded%28int%5B%5D%29) 
and keep track of handlers. These modules are what you want.